# Trouble Installing and Using cwiid Python Library

Tags: python, wiimote

I've been attempting to connect my Wiimote to my Raspberry Pi 4 B using the cwiid Python library, but I'm encountering issues with installation. Here's what I've tried so far:

code

```
mew@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/Wiimote $ sudo apt-get install python-cwiid
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-cwiid
```

Despite following various methods, I'm still unable to install the cwiid library. Could someone provide guidance on the correct installation process for cwiid on a Raspberry Pi 4 B? Additionally, any insights on how to establish a connection with the Wiimote using Python after installation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

It seems like you've tried a variety of methods to install cwiid on both Windows 11 and Raspberry Pi with Python 3 and Python 2.7. Let's try to troubleshoot and find a solution:

1. Windows 11 with Python 3:
   If you are working on Windows 11 with Python 3, you should be able to install cwiid using pip
2. Raspberry Pi 4 with Linux:
   For the Raspberry Pi with Linux, here are the steps to install cwiid

```
-sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends bluetooth -y
-sudo apt-get install python-cwiid
```

3. Cloning and Building from GitHub:

- git clone https://github.com/abstrakraft/cwiid.git
- git clone https://github.com/the-raspberry-pi-guy/Wiimote.git

4. Using Python 2.7 on Raspberry Pi:
   If you need to use Python 2.7 on the Raspberry Pi